# Why Sql Conditions (not in , not like , !=) not working on varchar value of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two columns and containing two records.

SQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TEST
(
    ID bigint NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION varchar(500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO #TEMP_TEST VALUES(1, 'obsolete')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TEST VALUES(2, NULL)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST
```

Total dummy records in `#TEMP_TEST` table

```
ID      | DESCRIPTION |
--------+-------------+
1       | obsolete    |
2       | NULL        |
```

Query with these conditions `=`, `like`, `in` are working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE LC2.DESCRIPTION ='obsolete'
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE LC2.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'obsolete'
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE LC2.DESCRIPTION IN ('obsolete')
```

Working fine with these results:

```
ID      | DESCRIPTION |
--------+-------------+
1       | obsolete    |
```

**Problem** :

Query with these conditions `!=`, `not like`, `not in` are not working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE LC2.DESCRIPTION != 'obsolete'
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'obsolete'
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('obsolete')
```

Results:

```
ID      | DESCRIPTION |
--------+-------------+
```

Expected results:

```
ID      | DESCRIPTION |
--------+-------------+
2       | NULL        |
```

What should I do to get expected result?

Kindly review and give a required answer or comment if any further condition is required for getting expected result.

Comment: no no that is typo mistake in asking question

Comment: null = 'anychar' => null, null != 'anyvarchar' => null. You must add a "OR IS NULL/ OR IS NOT NULL". Remeber null nearest english meaning is "A value I know nothing at all"

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas thank you so much your anwser is helpful

Comment: `SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE isnull(LC2.DESCRIPTION, '') NOT IN ('obsolete')` , @StanislovasKalašnikovas I tried isnull function with all condition (!=, not like, not in ), this is working fine. then what is better approach in between using `OR` and `ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OR` and It will work even if `ANSI_NULLS` is `ON`

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION != 'obsolete' OR LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'obsolete' OR LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('obsolete') OR LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL
```

Comment: This would be my preferred approach; turning non-ANSI null handling on seems like overkill when there's a simple ANSI-standard solution. Especially as ["In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

Comment: could you please help me why it is not working with `AND` `SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'obsolete' AND LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL`

Comment: When `LC2.DESCRIPTION` is `NULL` then `LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'obsolete'` isn't true. (`LC2.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'obsolete'` also isn't true.) If one part of an AND condition is false, then the whole condition is false. We're using `OR` because you're specifically saying that you want to return rows where `LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL`, and `...OR LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL` will do that regardless of what the other condition is.

Answer (score 6):

This is because of three valued logic in SQL Server. Predicate can evaluate to:

- true
- false
- unknown

When you are comparing data in SQL Server you should always think about possible `NULL`s. Consider these predicates:

```
where 1=1 => evaluates to true
where 2=1 => evaluates to false
where 1=null => evaluates to unknown
where null=null => evaluates to unknown
```

So comparing `NULL` to any value, even with `NULL` evaluates to UNKNOWN`.
Now you should know how`WHERE`clause works. It returns rows where predicate evaluates to`TRUE` only!

In your case the predicate:

```
WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION != 'obsolete'
```

will evaluate to:

```
obselete != obselete => false
obselete != null => unknown
```

So there are no rows where predicate evaluates to `TRUE` and you get nothing as a result.

As for the question what should you do, you can do the following:

```
WHERE ISNULL(LC2.DESCRIPTION, 'not absolete') != 'obsolete'
```

but here your predicate is not `SARG`able and you will not gain from indexes if any is created for `LC2.DESCRIPTION` column.

The standard way is to use `OR`:

```
WHERE LC2.DESCRIPTION != 'obsolete' OR LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL
```

Comment: select * from #TEMP_TEST where null=null ==>  select * from #TEMP_TEST where 1=1

Comment: No, you are wrong! `where 1=1` will return all rows. `where null=null` will return nothing.

Comment: but as i tried it with above queries it is returning all rows

Comment: can you give me demo query on where null=null which return nothing

Comment: `select * from #TEMP_TEST where null=null` , I tried this query on `where null=null` this is returning all rows

Comment: are you sure you have ansi nulls ON?

Comment: you are right, `select * from #TEMP_TEST where null=null` is returning all rows because i had already ansi nulls OFF, now i have changed ansi null to ON then it is not returning any row. so if there is `ansi nulls ON` and `where null=null => evaluates to unknown` . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check that `ansi_nulls` is ON/OFF in your case. When it is set to ON then 'obsolete' <> NULL is an UNKNOWN and hence you dont get any result.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION !='obsolete'
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'obsolete'
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('obsolete')
```

Also to note that setting the ansi_null to OFF is not a recommended way and is not considered a good practice so you can use it like this ie, try to add a check for NULL condition:

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION != 'obsolete' OR LC2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL
```

Comment: SET ANSI_NULLS  is ON

Comment: @islamuddin:- Try to turn it OFF and then try your query :)

Comment: Setting ansi_nulls off is a bad idea and is a deprecated feature, meaning that it will be removed in a future version of SQL server.

Comment: @BateTech:- Indeed, I have added that in my answer that it is not a recommeded way.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way,

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TEST LC2 WHERE  LC2.DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('obsolete')
```

**ANSI_NULLS ON**

*This option specifies the setting for ANSI NULL comparisons. When this is on, any query that compares a value with a null returns a 0. When off, any query that compares a value with a null returns a null value.*

Comment: setting ansi nulls off is bad practice and deprecated (don't guarantee to work in future versions) in fact MS already anounced planning to get rid of that option at all. Meaning in a future version trying to set ansi nulls off ill throw an exception